# Calculation Between Datetimepicker and Textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, datetimepicker

i have a `datimepicker` Date Recieve and Assumed Date of Arrival and a `textbox` of LeadTime
all i can see in the internet is a calculation between two `datetimepicker` , but i want to do is just like this

```
int date=0;
            int lead_time = Int16.Parse(tb_leadtime.Text);
            date = dt_recieve.Value - lead_time;
            dt_arrival.Value = "MMM/" + date + "/yyyy";
```

any suggestion and opinion will be helpful.

Comment: Please read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) because your code is vulnerable to it.

Comment: Are you trying to show one date, or one date per row?

Comment: @ThomasLangston yes only the date in CounterChecking the counterchecking table all of them is in the datagridview them the date is only datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

I see a big problem in your code. Appending textbox.Text directly to an sql string is not safe. You are exposing your system for sql injection. I would recommend always use Stored Procedures with definite input parameters and errors. For your actual question could you please write a little more detail to understand the problem better? I may be abel to help you.